# Stiefel-Whitney Class associated to Quadratic Form

Tags: nt.number-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology, stiefel-whitney

I am trying to understand a bit of Milnor's paper "Algebraic K-Theory and Quadratic Forms".  I guess, first things first.  Why did Milnor come up with such an invariant?

For any number field (such as $F = \mathbb{Q}$), he defines $K_n F$ as related to the group:

> By definition $K_n F$ is the target group of the $n$-linear function from $F^\ast \times \dots \times F^\ast$ to an additive group, satisfying the condition that $a_1 \times \dots \times a_n$ should map to zero whenever $a_i + a_{i+1} = 1$

It doesn't explain why he constructed such a thing.  Apparently, there are Stiefel-Whitney invariants associtated to quadratic modules over $F$.

Perhaps an example could be $\mathbb{Q}^2$ with the bilinar map $\langle x, y \rangle = x^2 + 11y^2$, but I'm not sure if class numbers are appropriate to discuss over $\mathbb{Q}$ (since they're usually over $\mathbb{Z}$).  However, there are many nice $p$-adic invariants over rational quadratic forms.  Even the trivial quadratic form $\mathbb{Q}^3$, with $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ it would be good to understand how strong approximation holds.  But Milnor's invariants might not be relevant to any of that.

Instead he shows us a way to get at the Galois group of the separable closure of $F$ (which I guess is smaller than the algebraic closure).
$$ K_\ast F / 2 K_\ast F \simeq H^\ast ( G_F ; \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) $$

The K-groups of number fields, seem to encode some crucial information about algebraic numbers, but they way Milnor has written it just looks like a rather arbitrary linear map.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_K-theory
- [Algebraic K Theory and Quadratic Forms](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PID=GDZPPN002088274) 

  Milnor, J., Algebraic K-theory and Quadratic Forms, Invent. Math. 9 (1970), 318–344.

Comment: Your $K_nF$ is the $n$-th Milnor $K$-group of the field $F$. You can motivate them by motivic cohomology. There is not only the Milnor conjecture relating Milnor $K$-theory and Galois cohomology you mentioned, but also the Milnor conjecture on quadratic forms relating $\bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty I^n/I^{n+1}$ to $\bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty K_n(F)/2$ for $I$ the fundamental ideal of the Witt ring $W(F)$.

Comment: The Hilbert symbol is an example of bilinear map satisfying the condition stated by Milnor.